# How to integrate platform specific (Android and iOs) Sdk's into my Kotlin Multiplatform (KMM) project

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

I am very new in KMM and I am in a situation where I need to integrate a library that is not a part of KMM. Instead, it has separate Android and iOS SDKs. I am unsure about how to integrate it into my KMM project. Do I need to create a KMM library, or is there another way to incorporate these platform-specific libraries into my KMM project?

Answer (score 0):

Like pretty much everything in tech, "it depends". That's a big question. In summary, you have two basic options:

- Create an interface that represents what you want to do from shared code, and pass in an implementation from each platform.
- Add the dependency on the Android side, and use cinterop on the iOS side, and "talk" to them that way.

I gave a talk about this last year. It goes into more detail. Good luck:

https://www.droidcon.com/2022/06/28/sdk-design-and-publishing-for-kotlin-multiplatform-mobile/